# How to minimize conflicts in merging with the CVS Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, version-control, merge, cvs, branching-and-merging

[image: scenario]

I am trying to execute the above merge scenario using Eclipse and the CVS plugin.  It works a lot like [this Eclipse branching article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-BranchingWithEclipseAndCVS/article2.html).

**The problem I am encountering is what I consider "incorrect conflicts".**
Shouldn't M2 be free of conflicts?

At the point after the commit tagged `PM1`, the two branches are the same.  Some work is done on `HEAD` (as `WD2`) and committed to `HEAD`.  A tag `W2` is created.  Now I want those changes in `p1test`.

The branch in the Eclipse project is set to `p1test` and a merge is done by selecting `HEAD` as the "Branch or version to be merged (end tag)", and `W1` as "Common base version (start tag)".  Since there have been no changes in `p1test`, I would have expected no conflicts in `M2`.  But that's not what I see.  The `WD2` work shows as conflicts.  That doesn't seem right since those files haven't been touched in the `p1test` branch.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did it right as your diagram comes from the original [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-BranchingWithEclipseAndCVS/article2.html).

Do you use CVS keywords (`$Revision$`, `$Author$`, `$Date$`, ...) in your text files ? Do conflicts concern lines with such keywords ?

I suggest you to test the merge operation with CVS command line *itself*:

- Do a fresh checkout of `p1test` branch
- Invoke `cvs update -kk -j W1 -j W2`
- You should have no conflict and be able to commit the resulting merge on `p1test` branch

The `-kk` option is required to avoid conflicts on keywords.

Comment: Thanks Yves.  The conflicts do not arise from the CVS keywords.  I'm really trying to get this to work "using Eclipse and the CVS plugin".

Comment: So from where your conflicts come from ? Does the command line executes without generating conflicts ?

Comment: have not figured out he command line, and not really inclined to. The conflicts show for any change on the WD2.

Comment: Is there any "end-of-line" trouble with your source files ? In that case the whole file is considered as modified... and of course cause conflicts

Comment: What about using "W2" as "end tag" instead of "HEAD". It matchs better the procedure even if I think it changes anything.